# Why the error information "unrecognized arguments" return?

Tags: python, pytorch, arguments

When I tried to use ArgumentParser() class to define the argument "epochs" as the training epoch of my CNN model with PyTorch, the system informed me this error. This is my code block:

```
# 2.1 define super arguments (training epochs for example)

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-e', '--epochs', default=10, type=int, 
                    help='number of epochs to train the VAE for')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

epochs = args['epochs']
```

When I executed it, the error was thrown out as:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-e EPOCHS]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-ae55ea85-75ab-4308-8b6a-3319e5b09a40.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

I do not know what this error information means and how to fix it. I never made any extra arguments with the prompt "-f". How can I deal with this error? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error message, I guess you are running the code in the jupyter notebook environment.
In jupyter notebook, if you want to use argparse, please modify the code to the following form：
args = vars(parser.parse_args(args=[]))